# How to track bytes sent in Nginx

Tags: nginx

I'm using NGinx as a large file content delivery server, I need to track how many bytes are sent to the client when they download a file. Then with some ID deduct the bandwidth from their account. Here is my Nginx config, but it doesnt seem to work. On my test server running on 8899 I dont get any hit no matter what.

```
location /test {
    try_files $uri @afterdownload;
    alias /home/ubuntu/test/;
    post_action @afterdownload;
}

location @afterdownload {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8899/?FileName=$uri&ClientIP=$remote_addr&body_bytes_sent=$body_bytes_sent&status=$request_completion;
    internal;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this module 
https://github.com/Lax/ngx_http_accounting_module

but I think you need to make customization to fit your case outside nginx along with this module.